# rails autocomplete gem to limit searches on locale parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

the following action is invoked for handling by the autcomplete gem

```
Started GET "/nations/autocomplete_nationtranslation_name?locale=en&term=erm"
```

Nationtranslation table has an indexed column

```
t.string   "locale"
```

the model defined with:

```
autocomplete :nationtranslation, :nome, full: true
autocomplete :nationtranslation, :nome, full: true, :extra_data => [:locale]
```

both return all possible values for all locales, whereas

```
autocomplete :nationtranslation, :nome, full: true, :extra_data => params[:locale]
```

returns `ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method 'params' for NationsController:Class`

How can autocomplete run the search with the scope of
  locale = params[:locale]
?

Comment: Which rails autocomplete gem are you exactly using?

Comment: using `rails3-jquery-autocomplete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to provide your own controller action method which is generated by `rails-jquery-autocomplete` gem by default.

```
class NationsController < ApplicationController

  # you don't really need this anymore
  # autocomplete :nationtranslation, :name

  def autocomplete_nationtranslation_name
    translations = Nationtranslation.where("name LIKE ? AND locale = ?", 
                                           "%#{params[:term]}%", 
                                           params[:locale])
                                    .order(:name)
    render json: translations.map { |t| {id: t.id, label: t.name, value: t.name} }    
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the proper direction.  But then I realised that the gem does something more in handling lower/upper case.  For whomever wants to follow this direction,  it required creating a column `name_downcase` (update_attributes by downcasing `name`) and the first line of the methods should also sanitize the case with `term = params[:term].downcase` and adjusting conditions to `"name_downcase LIKE ? AND locale = ?", "%#{term}%", params[:locale]`